# Determine if any frame has input focus?

Tags: focus

I have a function that gets called when idle, but I would like it to run only when a frame has input focus.

My current work around is to use `focus-in-hook` and `focus-out-hook` to change the behavior when idle, but I'd like to simplify it by just having one function that would check whether or not it had focus. Here's the code I am working with:

```
(use-package zone
  :ensure shut-up
  :commands (zone-when-idle)
  :bind ("C-c z" . zone)
  :init
  (setq zone-timeout 30)
  (defun zone-when-idle-and-focused ()
    "Use with `focus-in-hook' to only zone when our focus is back in Emacs."
    (zone-when-idle (or zone-timeout 30)))
  (defun zone-nodoze ()
    "Use with `focus-out-hook' so we don't zone when our focus is elsewhere."
    (let ((inhibit-message t)) (zone-leave-me-alone)))
  (add-hook 'focus-in-hook #'zone-when-idle-and-focused)
  (add-hook 'focus-out-hook #'zone-nodoze)
  (zone-when-idle zone-timeout))
```

Comment: Does the function `selected-frame` help any?

Comment: `selected-frame` doesn't seem to help; it reports the same frame whether or not the frame has input focus when the idle-timer function runs.

Comment: The following Emacs discussion on the mailing list (initiated by Marcin Borkowski) deals with this issue.  Perhaps there is something in there that will answer your question -- **How to determine (from Elisp) whether the Emacs frame has focus?**:  https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2015-11/msg00160.html

Comment: What Marcin asks in the thread sounds like exactly what I am looking for, but I couldn't find an answer that worked and, it seems, neither did he in that discussion.

Comment: Note that you can't know whether a terminal frame has input focus.

Comment: @Gilles for my use case around this question I run almost exclusively in a natively window managed frame, rather than emacs inside a terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Old question but if anyone else has the same problem `(frame-focus-state)` is available in Emacs 27.1 (and possibly before).

From the manual:

```
(frame-focus-state &optional FRAME)

Return FRAME’s last known focus state.
If nil or omitted, FRAME defaults to the selected frame.

Return nil if the frame is definitely known not be focused, t if
the frame is known to be focused, and ‘unknown’ if we don’t know.
```